# What's meaning of the inverted Greek letter iota “ι” in Principia Mathematica I* 14?

Tags: logic, notation, math-history

The inverted iota always followed by a variable as following:
(ιx)ϕx
Some book say the formula should be read "The x such that x is ϕ". Does it is meaning as following:
x=ϕ
assign ϕ to variable x?

Comment: So we could read it as "The X uniquely identified by the predicate Phi"

Comment: It is called definite description.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not an assignment. $\phi$ is a predicate. $(\iota x)\phi x$ is the one and only object $x$ for which the predicate $\phi$ is true.

For example, if $\phi x$ means "$x$ is the current monarch of the United Kingdom" then $(\iota x)\phi x$ denotes King Charles III. As another example, $(\iota x). x\ge 0\mathrel . x^2=3$ denotes the number $\sqrt 3$.

This is explained in the front matter of the *Principia*, including what the meaning is when there is no unique $x$ (either because there is none or because there is more than one). If the denoted predicate is not unique, then the truth value of the formula is false.

Comment: Dig it out, Is there inverted iota counterpart in modern symbols? Does the formula $(ιx).x≥0.x^2=3$ in modern symbol was as following: $(\exists x)x≥0 & x^2=3$ .

Comment: I don't think there is anything exactly like it in current use: it is based in Russell's theory of descriptions, which I don't think has been generally adopted.  I looked through the relevant articles in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy and did not find any more modern notation.  But there is some detailed discussion in http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-construction/#DefDes .  I think something like it could also be expressed using Poincaré's $\epsilon$ quantifier, but that is also not in common use.

Comment: Note to self: I recently read (in Suppes _Introduction to Logic_ 1957, p. 161, fn) that this unique description quantifier was introduced by Peano, but I have not yet been able to track down the source.  It does not appear to be in his 1889 _Principles of Arithmetic_.  In _Selected Works of Giuseppe Peano_, the editor, Kennedy, says “Between 1911 and 1915 [Peano] published six articles having ‘definition’ in the title.”  Perhaps it is one of these.

Comment: @MJD in the article [Frege, Peano and Russell on Descriptions: a Comparison](https://mulpress.mcmaster.ca/russelljournal/article/download/1968/1994), Francisco A. Rodríguez-Consuegra tracks down the source to Peano's _Studii di logica matematica_ (1897) as where the $\iota$ operator first appears.

Comment: @C7X: Do you expect text books to be revised with each geopolitical change? Can't people infer from context and the timestamp what's the point? Please avoid unnecessary edits.

Answer (score 10):

This is the descriptor operator. $(\iota x)\varphi x $ is the unique $x $ with the property specified by $\varphi $ (should it be the case that, indeed, there is precisely one such $x $). The Wikipedia entry on Principia has a very decent explanation of their notation.